# CSS Slideshow with wrong timing of last image

Tags: css, css-animations, slideshow, slide

I have a little problem with css3 slideshow. I am trying to run this https://www.cssscript.com/pure-css-css3-slideshow-with-image-panning-and-zooming-effect/ with 10 pictures.

And my problem is that all slides don't have same duration. Now my nine slides goes correct for 5 seconds each. But there is problem that last tenth image stops for much more time. I think over 10 seconds.

My source code is same as in example in link. Only changes are:

```
animation: slideShow 50s linear infinite 0s;
-o-animation: slideShow 50s linear infinite 0s;
-moz-animation: slideShow 50s linear infinite 0s;
-webkit-animation: slideShow 50s linear infinite 0s;

.pic-2 {
  animation-delay: 5s;
  -o-animation-delay: 5s;
  -moz--animation-delay: 5s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 5s;
```

and same for pic-3 with 10s ..... pic-10 with 45s

Is it possible to fix it?

Thanks for answers

Edit: Now my code in body for overall duration 40s is and it still not working:

```
<div class="pic-wrapper">
  <figure class="pic-1"></figure>
  <figure class="pic-2"></figure>
  <figure class="pic-3"></figure>
  <figure class="pic-4"></figure>
  <figure class="pic-5"></figure>
  <figure class="pic-6"></figure>
  <figure class="pic-7"></figure>
  <figure class="pic-8"></figure>
  <figure class="pic-9"></figure>
  <figure class="pic-10"></figure>
</div>

<style>          
 * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.pic-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

figure {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  /*animation*/

  animation: slideShow 40s linear infinite 0s;
  -o-animation: slideShow 40s linear infinite 0s;
  -moz-animation: slideShow 40s linear infinite 0s;
  -webkit-animation: slideShow 40s linear infinite 0s;
}

figurecaption {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  color: #fff;
}

.pic-1 {
  opacity: 1;
  background: url(pic1.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

.pic-2 {
  animation-delay: 4s;
  -o-animation-delay: 4s;
  -moz--animation-delay: 4s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 4s;
  background: url(pic2.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

.pic-3 {
  animation-delay: 8s;
  -o-animation-delay: 8s;
  -moz--animation-delay: 8s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 8s;
  background: url(pic3.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

.pic-4 {
  animation-delay: 12s;
  -o-animation-delay: 12s;
  -moz--animation-delay: 12s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 12s;
  background: url(pic4.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

.pic-5 {
  animation-delay: 16s;
  -o-animation-delay: 16s;
  -moz--animation-delay: 16s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 16s;
  background: url(pic5.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

.pic-6 {
  animation-delay: 20s;
  -o-animation-delay: 20s;
  -moz--animation-delay: 20s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 20s;
  background: url(pic6.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

.pic-7 {
  animation-delay: 24s;
  -o-animation-delay: 24s;
  -moz--animation-delay: 24s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 24s;
  background: url(pic7.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

.pic-8 {
  animation-delay: 28s;
  -o-animation-delay: 28s;
  -moz--animation-delay: 28s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 28s;
  background: url(pic8.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

.pic-9 {
  animation-delay: 32s;
  -o-animation-delay: 32s;
  -moz--animation-delay: 32s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 32s;
  background: url(pic9.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

.pic-10 {
  animation-delay: 36s;
  -o-animation-delay: 36s;
  -moz--animation-delay: 36s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 36s;
  background: url(pic10.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

/* keyframes*/

@keyframes slideShow {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform:scale(1);
    -ms-transform:scale(1);
  }
  4% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  24% {
    opacity: 1;    
  }
  28% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform:scale(1.1);
    -ms-transform:scale(1.1);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform:scale(1);
    -ms-transformm:scale(1);
  }    
 }

@-o-keyframes slideShow {
   0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -o-transform:scale(1);
  }
  4% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  24% {
    opacity: 1;    
  }
  28% {
    opacity: 0;
    -o-transform:scale(1.1);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    -o-transformm:scale(1);    
  }
}

@-moz-keyframes slideShow {
   0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transform:scale(1);
  }
  4% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  24% {
    opacity: 1;    
  }
  28% {
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transform:scale(1.1);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transformm:scale(1);    
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes slideShow {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform:scale(1);
  }
  4% {
    opacity: 1
  }
  24% {
    opacity: 1;    
  }
  28% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.1);
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transformm:scale(1);    
  }
}

</style>
```

Comment: What's the css for `.pic-10`? Post more code please

Comment: .pic-10 {
  animation-delay: 36s;
  -o-animation-delay: 36s;
  -moz--animation-delay: 36s;
  -webkit-animation-delay: 36s;
  background: url(picture.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}

Comment: It was 45s before

Comment: Well it should work with 45s, if it doesn't, you need to post more code, edit the question and post an simplified example